# Formatting cells based on multiple/adjacent text values

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I am trying to highlight shipping numbers based on the order status.

Here is an example/mock up:

Before Validation:

[image: Before Validation]

I have just added borders to (hopefully) make it easier to look at the shipping numbers and adjacent cells. And I am just using generic Item 1 / Item 2 as stock codes. Now if I apply a simple Conditional Format to highlight the shipping#s in green if the status READY, and in red if the status is NOT READY, it looks like this:

After Validation:

[image: After Validation]

This is not what I am looking to do. All the items for a shipping# need to have a READY status. So, the cells should look like this:

Proper Validation:

[image: Proper Validation]

Again, the item status needs to have all READY status to be highlighted green. If at least one is NOT READY, then it needs to be highlighted red. From here, I could add a filter and sort by green colour as that would give me all the ready shipping#s to add to our program to load to ship.

Could I achieve what I am trying to do by expanding my formula, or do I need to use a loop of some kind in VBA to look at all the cells and highlight accordingly? How do I go about highlighting all of the same shipping# the same colour? The formulas I am using in Conditional Formatting are **=A1="READY"** & **=A1="NOT READY"**.

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 conditional formatting rules based on the following formulas:

1. Green/READY: `=COUNTIF(B:B,B2)=COUNTIFS(B:B,B2,A:A,"READY")`
2. Red/NOT READY: `=COUNTIF(B:B,B2)<>COUNTIFS(B:B,B2,A:A,"READY")`

[image]